# Java executable doesn't start

Tags: java

I'm having a frustrating issue with a java program I have been working on. I have not had this issue often in the past and I have actually created many versions using this same code and had no problems.

Suddenly, executable JARs of this program will not start. I have tried running them through the command prompt with Java and I get message about the main class not being found.

I have done a search here and none of the answers work for me. I have tried the following:

- Removing the system library in the build path settings and adding it back. (The system library is [jre1.8.0_66]).
- Changing the compliance settings from 1.7 to 1.6. I don't have an option for 1.8 and the JDK check box that says "Use compliance from execution environment on Java Build Path" is disabled.
- Removing the main class and adding it back.
- Using the package and export options for libraries.

I'm really not sure what else to do. I've tried doing a rebuild on the project many times and also tried restarting eclipse and re-exporting. I'm certain that I am selecting the main class when in the export preferences.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated as this has become very frustrating.

Comment: How are you executing the jar from the command prompt?

Comment: Does your IDE have a way to point to the `main` class when creating the Jar?  Check that it is pointing correctly.

Comment: java {{jar name}} - Yes my IDE is pointing to the correct file. I have not changed anything since the last time I exported other than adding some new classes and making changes to previous classes.

Comment: Have you packed the manifest file in it containing information about the main class?

Comment: Tac, I've never had to do that before so I do not think so. Typically I just use Eclipse to do an export, select the main class and it's good to go. I'm talking about an executable jar file.

Comment: You have to show us details. Please edit your post to show the exact command you use to launch the jar, as well as the contents of your manifest file and the directory structure within the jar file.

Comment: I'm trying to deal with an executable jar file - There is no manifest for that. The only reason I used "cmd" was because I didn't know what else to do and I thought it might work for a fully-compiled executable jar file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, it seems to me that you are not executing your JAR correctly. As stated in the comments, you are executing your JAR with `java {jarname}`. This syntax would only work with running a compiled Java class with a `main` method. To run a JAR, use:

```
java -jar {jarname}
```

Comment: I'm talking about an executable jar file. The only reason that I used the cmd was because it won't open on double click. I tried your method too but it doesn't work.

Comment: Technically this solved my problem. Since I never use the cmd to run jar files I was doing it wrong. Doing it correctly gave me the stack trace which shown that the reason the jar doesn't work is because I imported a text-file in eclipse and did not add an "src" file alongside the executable-jar so I got a null pointer at start - thanks.